# why does this populate give me a not found function error?

Tags: mongodb

How can I execute this populate so that I can get the username of the person that does the tweet? I've tried with the `function getusername()` but it is not working as it gives me a `tweetsSchema.findOne is not a function` error.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var tweetsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    tweets: { type: String, required: true }, //reference to the associated book
    replies: { type: String, required: false },
    username: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }
  }
);

// Virtual for bookinstance's URL
function getUsername(tweets){
  return tweetsSchema.findOne({ tweets: tweets })
    .populate('username').exec((err, posts) => {
      console.log("Populated User " + username);
    })
}

getUsername()
//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('tweets', tweetsSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

currently the function you have defined is just a function and haven't defined on the Schema of yours and not exported.

you might want to use static in mongoose

```
tweetsSchema.static('getUsername', async function(tweets){
   return await tweetsSchema.findOne({ tweets: tweets })
    .populate('username').exec((err, posts) => {
      console.log("Populated User " + username);
    })
})
```